# Алгоритм выдачи сдачи

Tags: c#

Есть необходимость разработать алгоритм выдачи сдачи монетами. Погуглил и в большей степени наткнулся на варианты так называемого жадного алгоритма.
Сначала выдаём наибольшим номиналом и затем по оставшейся сумме идём вниз.
Но этот алгоритм сломается допустим о следующий пример.
В автомате есть 3 номинала в рублях:
5
2
1

Мне нужно выдать сдачу в 6 рублей. Соответственно по жадному алгоритму нужно бы выдать 5 и 1. Но допустим что в автомате есть одна 5 рублёвая монета и три 2 рублёвых, а рублей нет. А я уже в алгоритме приплюсую пятёрку и как тогда быть в таком случае? Как по алгоритму возвращаться назад и пересчитывать?

Comment: в такой постановке это задача о рюкзаке. Куча разных вариантов решения, все имеют существенный недостаток.

Comment: вообще монетоприемник должен уметь отдавать данные о монетах, которые он может выдать на сдачу, т.о. на старте алгоритма вы знаете какие монеты в наличии и можете скорректировать подведение алгоритма

Comment: так а известно заранее какие монеты есть а каких нет?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да я знаю какой номинал монет есть в автомате и в каком количестве.

Comment: Можно пробовать удалять из пула выбранных монет для сдачи монеты более крупного номинала по одной в случае неудавшейся укомплектации

Comment: 10 можно выдать любыми монетами, так что выдаём тем, что есть, отдавая преимущество крупным, а остальное как получится - там не так много вариантов.

Comment: В основе алгоритма должна лежать избыточность номиналов монет. Не стоит опустошать один из номиналов слишком быстро. Вторым условием можно взять кратность без остатка или раскидывание по номиналом обычным делением с остатком (10 % 5 = 0, 13 % 5 -> 3 % 2 -> 1 % 1). Третьим, желание получателя "выдать мелкими".